# Adobe reader XI not opening comments

Tags: adobe, adobe-reader

I was using adobe reader to write comments for students as I was marking (am a tutor). After marking around 50 assignments I went back to check some of the comments I had written and suddenly I couldn't open them (the comment). I can see the comment sticker/icon but am unable to click/view the comment and I'm not sure what is going on. I am using adobe reader version 11.

I can also open documents with comments from other people but the ones with my comments is there one giving problems. So I can see the comment icon is there but it's just not clickable. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try going on the comment panel and check if these comments appear.

Comment: I assume you mean Acrobat Reader, in which case you best bet for resolving this issue if the existing answers aren't sufficient, is to go to Adobes support page for this product and submit your issue there.

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/bd-p/acrobat

You're going to have much better luck posting where someone who works for Adobe may come across it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is still open, make sure you save it (or create a copy).

Then, restart Adobe Reader XI. The "Comment" button should be available to click on (I worked with version 11.0.23 and it happened once and fixed after restart).

Once you click on that, there should be another button named "Comments List" listing the different comments and locations, including the comments' texts.

In general, the current Adobe reader version is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and it is backward compatible (Meaning your current file will be displayed with the same features on it), so I would suggest using the latest version.